# Angular Material slider component with three thumbs

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, slider

I am working on a project that uses angular material for the ui.

Now, I need something like a Slider component with three thumbs.
Let's say one for minimum, one for maximum and one that can be moved in between.

For example, I have a video player running in a loop, but it only plays the video from the minimum to the maximum values. The third thumb shows the current position of the video stream.
I want to be able to set the range of the allowed minimum and maximum value, while the third thumb dynamically updates the position.
The user should also be able to set the current position of the third thumb to jump inside the allowed range.

What I mean already exists for [react material](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/#removed-track) (with temperatures), but I have not been able to find anything similar for angular material. I use angular material 17.

Does anybody know of a library I can use with such a component.

If not, how can I implement it by myself? It seems that I can not just use the slider component and extend it by a third value.